# How to convert snippet placeholder from CamelCase to snake_case

Tags: regex, camelcasing, vscode-snippets, snakecasing

I would like to create a VS Code snippet where I input a part in `CamelCase`, and the same string is output in `snake_case` at some other place in the snippet.

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277998/vs-code-how-to-convert-snippet-placeholder-from-camelcase-to-screaming-snake-ca/51394767?noredirect=1#comment119355466_51394767) Here's my attempted snippet, but I have a trailing `_` that needs to be removed by hand, not ideal:

```json
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": "${1} -> ${1/([A-Z])+([a-z]+)/${1:/downcase}${2}_/g}"
},
```

Comment: This has been answered else where on stackoverflow [VSCode user snippet to convert to snake case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086528/1171746)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"camelToSnakeCase": {
  "prefix": "test",
  "body": [

    "${1} -> ${1/([A-Z][a-z]+$)|([A-Z][a-z]+)/${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase}${2:+_}/g}"
  ],
  "description": "transform from CamelCase to snake_case"
}
```

In order to differentiate between some last capture group like `Abcd` and the preceding capture groups, I used an alternation:

`([A-Z][a-z]+$)|([A-Z][a-z]+)`  must be in this order

so group 1 will be at the end of the input because of the `$` indicator and group 2 will not be at the end.  And group 2s will always have at least one more group after them. Then, using the conditional `${2:+_}` only insert an underscore if there is a group 2 - because there must be a following group 1.

---

This keybinding version also works if you have a different workflow:

```
{
    "key": "alt+3",                        // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "sequence": [
            "cursorWordLeftSelect",            
            "editor.action.transformToSnakecase",
            "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
            // "cursorLineEnd"                   // if you want this
        ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
}
```

Type your word and trigger the keybinding.  Uses the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).